# Deserialization complex Json (class)

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a Json File like this.

```
{
"_request": {
    "api_ver": 1,
    "route": "/api/v2/u/SunDwarf-21353/stats/general"
},
"average_stats": {
    "damage_done_avg": 3987.0,
    "deaths_avg": 5.68,
    "defensive_assists_avg": 0.0,
    "eliminations_avg": 10.47,
    "final_blows_avg": 6.12,
    "healing_done_avg": 589.0,
    "melee_final_blows_avg": 0.03,
    "objective_kills_avg": 3.06,
    "objective_time_avg": 0.007222222222222223,
    "offensive_assists_avg": 0.0,
    "solo_kills_avg": 2.3,
    "time_spent_on_fire_avg": 0.008055555555555555
},
"battletag": "SunDwarf-21353",
"game_stats": {
    "cards": 36.0,
    "damage_done": 478462.0,
    "damage_done_most_in_game": 13303.0,
    "deaths": 682.0,
    "defensive_assists": 39.0,
    "defensive_assists_most_in_game": 11.0,
    "eliminations": 1257.0,
    "eliminations_most_in_game": 26.0,
    "environmental_deaths": 12.0,
    "environmental_kills": 8.0,
    "final_blows": 735.0,
    "final_blows_most_in_game": 16.0,
    "games_played": 120.0,
    "games_won": 59.0,
    "healing_done": 70670.0,
    "healing_done_most_in_game": 7832.0,
    "kpd": 1.84,
    "medals": 304.0,
    "medals_bronze": 102.0,
    "medals_gold": 100.0,
    "medals_silver": 102.0,
    "melee_final_blows": 4.0,
    "melee_final_blows_most_in_game": 2.0,
    "multikill_best": 3.0,
    "multikills": 5.0,
    "objective_kills": 368.0,
    "objective_kills_most_in_game": 10.0,
    "objective_time": 0.8880555555555555,
    "objective_time_most_in_game": 0.026944444444444444,
    "offensive_assists": 13.0,
    "offensive_assists_most_in_game": 7.0,
    "recon_assists": 9.0,
    "solo_kills": 277.0,
    "solo_kills_most_in_game": 16.0,
    "time_played": 15.0,
    "time_spent_on_fire": 0.9961111111111111,
    "time_spent_on_fire_most_in_game": 0.08833333333333333
},
"overall_stats": {
    "avatar": "https://blzgdapipro-a.akamaihd.net/game/unlocks/0x02500000000008E8.png",
    "comprank": null,
    "games": 120,
    "level": 24,
    "losses": 61,
    "prestige": 0,
    "win_rate": 49,
    "wins": 59
},
"region": "eu"
}
```

So I want to Deserialie this in C# . so I create with json2csharp.com the Classes.

Now its possible to instantiate all these classes, but this is bad I don't need a instance of GameStats, or average_stats.

What's my line here, how I can make this class not creatable?

sorry for my english, hope you can follow my problem :D

best regards. alex

Comment: Can you show your code ? How do you instantiate all these classes?

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove unwanted properties form `RootObject`

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Request _request { get; set; }
    //public AverageStats average_stats { get; set; }
    public string battletag { get; set; }
    //public GameStats game_stats { get; set; }
    public OverallStats overall_stats { get; set; }
    public string region { get; set; }
}
```

Deserializer omits them.

Answer (score 0):

So you mean you don't know how to use a deserializer? 
Take a look at [this link](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm)

Simply do it like this:

```
string json = @"{
  'Email': 'james@example.com',
  'Active': true,
  'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
  'Roles': [
    'User',
    'Admin'
  ]
}";

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
// james@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your classes nested to stop classes being shown in intellisense and add parameterless private constructors. Don't worry about private constructors, Json.NET uses reflection to instantiate your classes.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public class GameStats
    {
        private GameStats() { }
        //Code omitted
    }

    public class Request
    {
        private Request() { }
        //Code omitted
    }

    public class AverageStats
    {
        private AverageStats() { }
        //Code omitted
    }

    public class OverallStats
    {
        private OverallStats() { }
        //Code omitted
    }

    public Request _request { get; set; }
    public AverageStats average_stats { get; set; }
    public string battletag { get; set; }
    public GameStats game_stats { get; set; }
    public OverallStats overall_stats { get; set; }
    public string region { get; set; }
}
```

Compiler gives error:

```
//'RootObject.GameStats.GameStats()' is inaccessible due to its protection level
var myClass = new RootObject.GameStats();
```